# error IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Tags: vb.net, csv, oledb

I am facing error on this,when i execute this line of code then the error IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005). appeared.

My code

```
   Dim sql As New OleDbCommand("Select Distinct(LOTID) = CASE when LOTID LIKE '%-%' THEN isnull(parsename(replace(LOTID,'-','.'),1),LOTID) ELSE isnull(parsename(replace(LOTID,'-','.'),1),LOTID) END, COUNT(isAvail) as isAvail from ["+csvFile +"] where isAvail = 0 group by LOTID, isAvail ", connx)
```

I have tried to bracket all the reserved words like this

```
Select Distinct([LOTID]) = CASE when [LOTID] LIKE '%-%' THEN isnull(parsename(replace([LOTID],'-','.'),1),[LOTID]) ELSE isnull(parsename(replace([LOTID],'-','.'),1),[LOTID]) END, COUNT([isAvail]) as [isAvail] from [" + csvFile + "] where [isAvail] = 0 group by [LOTID], [isAvail]
```

but the same error still appearing.

Comment: AFAIK `parsename` is an SQL Server function. Are you using OLEDB provider for SQL Server? You should check description part of the error to found possible cause.

Comment: Is this Access? Try pasting it into Access and see what errors you get. I think some of this is just not supported in Access.